# How to solve this method override and polymorphism problem that have different scope?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

What will be the result of attempting to compile and run the following program?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ref1 = new C();
        B ref2 = (B) ref1;
        System.out.println(ref2.g());
    }
}

class A {
    private int f(){
        return 0;
    }
    public int g(){
        return 3;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    private int f(){
        return 1;
    }
    public int g(){
        return f();
    }
}

class C extends B{
    public int f(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I tried it and got the answer 1, but I didn't know why.

I modified the following code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ref1 = new C();
        B ref2 = (B) ref1;
        System.out.println(ref2.g());
    }
}
```

to

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ref1 = new C();
        System.out.println(ref1.g());
        B ref2 = (B) ref1;
        System.out.println(ref2.g());
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
1
1
```

I can't understand why both `ref1` and `ref2` are 1 regardless of whether the type is cast to B.

However, if I remove both public and private, like this

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ref1 = new C();
        B ref2 = (B) ref1;
        System.out.println(ref2.g());
    }
}

class A {
    int f(){
        return 0;
    }
    int g(){
        return 3;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    int f(){
        return 1;
    }
    int g(){
        return f();
    }
}

class C extends B{
    int f(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The output becomes 2.

I wonder if this has something to do with private and public too?

Comment: a private method cannot be overriden in Java. you are 'hiding' it, the inner workings of those two situations are different

Comment: Thank you. So are the f-functions in C and the f-functions in B both problematic?

Comment: they are not "problematic", they are just hiding the original method instead of overriding them

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured it out. By the way, I made a mistake,
f is not a function, but a method, sorry.

Comment: indeed, Java doesn't have functions.

Comment: I put my understanding in the answer, could you please help me to see if there is any problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is:

`ref1` is of class `A` and refers to class `C`.

The superclass of `C` is `B`.

The `f()` method in class `B` is `private`, that is, the subclass is "hiding", so it has not been "copied" to the subclass `C`, so it seems to be overriding, but it is actually a new method belonging to the subclass `C`, but it "just happens" to have the same name as the method in the parent class.

Moreover, there is no `g()` in class `C`, so `g()` in `B` is used, and the return is `f()` in class `B`.

So the result is 1.

However, if the `private` and `public` are removed, then `C` can override the
`f()` method in `B`, and at this time `g()` will be linked to the `f()` method of `C`.

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, just one note: if both `public` and `private` modifiers are removed, then its visibility is a "default", which will be overrideable by subclasses in the same package only.

Comment: However, being `public` will allow it to be overrideable by any subclass. (reference: https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers)